# I am not able to import the test_app model in the core/view.py

Tags: python, django

I want to import the Test_app class in `core/view.py` I am not able to import test_app in core, I also added `test_app` and installed the app in `setting.py`. But I'm still not able to import.

See the image below for details.

[image: code]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow ! Please try not to post images of code / errors. Read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: you need to add a `__init__.py` file inside of "puddle_app" so the different modules can see each other.

Comment: You could import the model file directly with `from test_app.models import *`

Comment: __init__.py is already present in puddle but same error @ASimpleProgrammer

Comment: @Nealium I am trying  to  the same bt test_app is not getting access in core/views.py